# How do I hyperlink with ng-href in <td> elements?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, hyperlink

I have a table, and for one of the columns, I'm trying to hyperlink a url using a single word, like "Here". However, the column is showing up as blank (as well as getting an "attribute ng-href not allowed" warning on intelliJ. This is what the table looks like, with the last  line being my attempt to hyperlink:

```
<tr>
<td ng-bind="order.paid | date:'short'"></td>
<td ng-bind="order.totalQty"></td>
<td ng-bind="order.total.pretty" ng-if="!store.shopifyInstalled"></td>
<td><a ng-href="order.shopifyReceiptUrl" ng-bind="Here" ng-if="store.shopifyInstalled"></a></td>
</tr>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The label of the link goes after the `<a>` tag and before `</a>`

Comment: `ng-bind="Here"` is looking for a scope property `$scope.Here`. Could quote it to be string `ng-bind="'Here'"` but easier to just add it as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the curly braces `{{}}` to put your model and remove the `ng-bind` directive.

```
<tr>
<td ng-bind="order.paid | date:'short'"></td>
<td ng-bind="order.totalQty"></td>
<td ng-bind="order.total.pretty" ng-if="!store.shopifyInstalled"></td>
<td><a ng-href="{{order.shopifyReceiptUrl}}" ng-if="store.shopifyInstalled">Here</a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be Done in Two Ways:

First defining a var with ng-init:

```
<td><a ng-href="order.shopifyReceiptUrl" ng-bind="var_name" ng-init="var_name='Here'" ng-if="store.shopifyInstalled"></a></td>
```

Second Using custom Text:

```
<td><a ng-href="order.shopifyReceiptUrl" ng-if="store.shopifyInstalled">HERE</a></td>
```